# Saving a web page with a command line

Tags: debian, firefox

I'm trying to save a dynamically generated web page following a request in a Firefox browser like
"http://*****.jsp"

"wget http://****.jsp"  will yield the complete script, but I'm interested in downloading and saving the web page following the request using a command line, noting that the address bar stays the same.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sniff the traffic with a browser tool to see what `POST` or `GET` arguments are being sent and in what format (form encoded, raw json string, etc) - the browser consoles (network area) or extensions like Fiddler let you do this.

You can mimic the `POST` and `GET` calls with tools like Postman (GUI) or `curl` on the command line, or using various programming languages and their libraries.  You could even go crazy and simply telnet to the port (or use `sslclient` for https) and issue `GET` or whatever commands and input by hand.

Notes -

other than `GET` and `POST` you may see `DELETE`, `PUT` or other even more infrequently used http verbs.

be prepared to have to pass cookie or session token info in headers (the tools mentioned will show and/or allow this)

if the site is using a javascript framework, that will complicate getting/rendering out what you really want but the browser tools and extensions make it easier.